# FetchType.LAZY in ManyToMany doesnot work

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, lazy-initialization

I'm having a problem with, `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, it just doesn't work. I've already spent a lot of time solving this problem, can anyone help with this? I'll be very thankful. I have a genre and a country that are associated with movie manyTomany. No matter how hard I try to initialize the LAZY download, it doesn't work.I need the movie to have EAGER, and the genre and country to have LAZY.
I expect to get movie with its genre and country, But with SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = 1 - I get an endless loop, although genre and country has LAZY download.
[image]
Sample code - below

Entities:
Movie

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(of = {"id", "year", "name"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "year"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    **********
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_genre",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")})
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_country",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")})
    private Set<Country> countries = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Genre

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = "movies")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "movies")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Genre {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "genres")
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Country

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = "movies")
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "movies")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "countries")
    private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieService movieService;

    @Autowired
    private CountryService countryService;

    @Autowired
    private GenreService genreService;

    @GetMapping("movie")
    public List<Movie> getMovieMovie(){
        return movieService.getAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("movie/add")
    public Movie create(){
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("test");
        movie.setImg("test");
        movie.setTime("test");
        movie.setYear((short) 2332);
        movie.setMovieLink("test");
        movie.getCountries().add(countryService.getCountry(1));
        movie.getGenres().add(genreService.getGenre(1));
        return movieService.create(movie);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class MovieService {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    
    public List<Movie> getAll(){
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public Movie create(Movie mocie){
        return movieRepository.save(mocie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/) and review [ask].  Saying *it doesn't work* is completely useless. 
How does it not work?  1. Gives no results at all. Then what is expected. 2. Gives incorrect results. Then what does it produce and what do you expect. 3.Gives an error. If so what specifically is the complete error.  Further table definitions (ddl) with sample data and expected results, as text - **no images** are extremely helpful (so of required).

Comment: @Belayer I expect to get movie with its genre and country, But with SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = 1 - I get an endless loop, although genre and country has LAZY download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy loading works as expected, as it loads all data lazy.

What you are looking for is a way to break loop in the bi-directional mapping.

There you can use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` that you have to set on the relationships.

Please also read this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion